# Error: Argument or block definition required

Tags: terraform, block, definition, required

I have a problem

```
    Error: Argument or block definition required
on ec2.tf line 78, in resource "aws_instance" "myec2":
78:
An argument or block definition is required here.
```

My code present in my file ec2.tf

```
    resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  instance = aws_instance.myec2.id
  vpc      = true
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo PUBLIC IP: ${aws_eip.lb.public_ip} ; ID: ${aws_instance.myec2.id} ; AZ: ${aws_instance.myec2.availability_zone}; >> infos_ec2.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: The code that you have shared doesn't correspond to the error. Please share the aws_instace resource named "myec2"

Comment: please share resource "aws_eip" "myec2" block

Comment: resource "aws_instance" "myec2" {
  ami             = data.aws_ami.app_ami.id
  instance_type   = var.instancetype
  key_name        = "devops-loic"
  tags            = var.aws_common_tag
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.allow_ssh_http_https.name}"]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1.12",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("./devops-laeno.pem")
      host        = self.public_ip
    }
  }